# Bloomberg - get real world prices from the API

Tags: bloomberg

For a number of financial instruments, Bloomberg scales the prices that are shown in the Terminal - for example:

- FX Futures at CME: e.g. `ADZ3 Curncy` (Dec-2013 AUD Futures at CME) show as 93.88 (close on 04-Oct-2013), whereas the actual (CME) market/settlement price was 0.9388
- FX Rates: sometimes FX rates are scaled - this may vary by which way round the FX rate is asked for, so `EURJPY Curncy` (i.e. JPY per EUR) has a `BGN` close of 132.14 on 04-Oct-2013. The inverse (EUR per JPY) would be 0.007567. However, for `JPYEUR Curncy` (i.e. EUR per JPY), `BGN` has a close of 0.75672 for 04-Oct-2013.
- FX Forwards: Depending on whether you are asking for rates or forward points (which can be [set by overrides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929178/in-bloomberg-api-how-do-you-specify-to-get-fx-forwards-as-a-spread-rather-than-a))... if you ask for rates, you might get these in terms of the original rate, so for `EURJPY1M Curncy`, `BGN` has a close of 132.1174 on 04-Oct-2013. But if you ask for forward points, you would get these scaled by some factor - i.e. -1.28 for `EURJPY1M Curncy`.

Now, I am not trying to criticise Bloomberg for the way that they represent this data in the Terminal. Goodness only knows when they first wrote these systems, and they have to maintain the functionality that market practitioners have come to know and perhaps love... In that context, scaling to the significant figures might make sense.

However, when I am using the API, I want to get *real-world, actual prices*. Like... the actual price at the exchange or the actual price that you can trade EUR for JPY.

So... how can I do that?

Well... the approach that I have come to use is to find the `FLDS` that communicate this scaling information, and then I fetch that value to reverse the scale that they have applied to the values. For futures, that's `PX_SCALING_FACTOR`. For FX, I've found `PX_POS_MULT_FACTOR` most reliable. For FX forward points, it's `FWD_SCALE`.

(It's also worth mentioning that how these are applied vaires - so `PX_SCALING_FACTOR` is what futures prices should be *divided* by, `PX_POS_MULT_FACTOR` is what FX rates should be *multipled* by, and `FWD_SCALE` is how many decimal places to divide the forward points by to get to a value that can be added to the actual FX rate.)

The problem with that is that it doubles the number of fetchs I have to make, which adds a significant overhead to my use of the API (reference data fetches also seem to take longer than historical data fetches.) (FWIW, I'm using the API in Java, but the question should be equally applicable to using the API in Excel or any of the other supported languages.)

I've thought about finding out this information and storing it somewhere... but I'd really like to not have to hard code that. Also, that would require to spend a very long time finding out the right scaling factors for all the different instruments I'm interested in. Even then, I would have no guarantee that they wouldn't change their scale on me at some point!

What I would really like to be able to do is apply an override in my fetch that would allow me specify what scale should be used. (And no, the fields above do not seem to be override-able.) I've asked the "helpdesk" about this on lots and lots of occasions - I've been badgering them about it for about 12 months, but as ever with Bloomberg, nothing seems to have happened.

So...

- has anyone else in the SO community faced this problem?
- has anyone else found a way of setting this as an override?
- has anyone else worked out a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you seem to have all the available information at hand and there is not much more you can do. But these conventions are stable over time so it is fine to store the scales/factors instead of fetching the data everytime (the scale of EURGBP points will always be 4).

For FX, I have a file with:

- number of decimal (for spot, points and all-in forward rate)
- points scale
- spot date

To answer you specific questions:

- FX Futures at CME: on `ADZ3 Curncy` > `DES` > `3`:

  > For this specific contract, the price is quoted in cents/AUD instead of exchange convention USD/AUD in order to show greater precision for both the futures and options. Calendar spreads are also adjusted accordingly. Please note that the tick size has been adjusted by 0.01 to ensure the tick value and contract value are consistent with the exchange.

  Not sure there is much you can do about this, apart from manually checking the factor...
- FX Rates: PX_POS_MULT_FACTOR is your best bet indeed - note that the value of that field for a given pair is extremely unlikely to change. Alternatively, you could follow market conventions for pairs and AFAIK the rates will always be the actual rate. So use EURJPY instead of JPYEUR. The major currencies, in order, are: EUR, GBP, AUD, NZD, USD, CAD, CHF, JPY. For pairs that don't involve any of those you will have to fetch the info.
- FX Forwards: the points follow the market conventions, but the scale can vary (it is 4 most of the time, but it is 3 for GBPCZK for example). However it should not change over time for a given pair.

Comment: Thanks - this is helpful (at the very least, this reassures me that I'm not missing anything!). Two comments (more for future readers...): i) sometimes the DES pages are wrong / inconsistent with the actual FLDS values - where I have found this, I have raised this with Bloomberg, and they usually fix it; and ii) sometimes these field values do change (and yes, that can be quite disruptive when it happens...)

Comment: Oh - and on FX rates, I want to be able to support FX rates which ever way they user asks for them. However, as you I advise, put these into the 'market convention', and then flip if necessary. Beyond the majors you cover, I have found the following [New York Fed document](http://www.newyorkfed.org/fxc/2005/fxc051206c.pdf) helpful. Not all data providers / counterparties follow this, but for the most part it seems that they do...

Comment: Apologies for the barrage of comments - are you aware of any other products where Bloomberg scales the prices/values?

Comment: @amaidment I'd be interested in knowing what values you have seen change. Thanks for the Fed doc.

Comment: Here is a spreadsheet with the FX decimals&scales which should be up to date: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i6hyiyote0s00y3/FX%20Conventions.xlsx

Comment: Regarding other products, I mostly deal with equities (including options&futures) and FX - I don't think there is anything special on equities or equity derivatives (there is a contract size on derivaties but not a weird pricing policy like what you saw on the AUD contract).

Comment: it was a while (over a year ago), but I *think* it was the JPYEUR rate (n.b. wrong way round)... that was when I switched to fetch everything the normal way round and do the flip myself.

Comment: I don't think it can happen on a pair following the convention (EURJPY) but to be honest I don't track the other pairs much so can't say if that is an exception or not. I would have thought (and hoped) it is...