# R blpapi forward spread as points or outright

Tags: blpapi

I am using the blpapi package in R to download FX forward prices. In the formula I want to specify the setting to download forward prices as points or as outright prices. I have tried the following:

```
conn <- blpConnect()
sdate <- as.Date("1998-12-31") 
edate <- Sys.Date()-1

vFWD        <- c("EURAUD1M Curncy")

opts.daily <- c("periodicitySelection"="DAILY","nonTradingDayFillMethod"="PREVIOUS_VALUE","nonTradingDayFillOption"="NON_TRADING_WEEKDAYS")
opts.monthly <- c("periodicitySelection"="MONTHLY","nonTradingDayFillMethod"="PREVIOUS_VALUE","nonTradingDayFillOption"="NON_TRADING_WEEKDAYS")
opts.fwd <- c("FWD_CURVE_QUOTE_FORMAT"="OUTRIGHTS")

dfwd        <- bdh(securities = vFWD, c("PX_LAST"), start.date = sdate, end.date = edate, options = opts.daily, overrides = opts.fwd, con = defaultConnection())
```

** for Java coding the answer is here: [In Bloomberg API how do you specify to get FX forwards as a spread rather than absolute values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929178/in-bloomberg-api-how-do-you-specify-to-get-fx-forwards-as-a-spread-rather-than-a/2929463#2929463)

Answer (score 0):

Use `"OUTRIGHT"`, not `"OUTRIGHTS"` as your override option value.